# Create custom controller

Tags: php, magento

I use magento 1.9.2.4

I want to create a custom controller and followed some tutorials but nothing works i get everytime 404 not found.

this is my code:

**app/etc/modules/Demo_App.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!DOCTYPE config>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Demo_App>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends />
        </Demo_App>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Demo/App/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!DOCTYPE config>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Demo_App>
            <version>0.0.0</version>
        </Demo_App>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <apps>
                 <class>Demo_App_Model</class>
            </apps>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <apps>
                <class>Demo_App_Block</class>
            </apps>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <apps>
                <class>Demo_App_Helper</class>
            </apps>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <apps>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <frontName>apps</frontName>
                    <module>Demo_App</module>
                </args>
            </apps>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Demo/App/controllers/IndexController.php**

```
<?php

class Demo_App_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

 public function indexAction()
{
    echo "hello world! i am the index.";
}
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: @clear cache and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `<apps>` inside `<routers>` and at all other places except `<frontname>` , use `<app>`.  This tag should be the lowercase version of you module name

So the `config.xml` would look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!DOCTYPE config>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Demo_App>
            <version>0.0.0</version>
        </Demo_App>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <app>
                 <class>Demo_App_Model</class>
            </app>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <app>
                <class>Demo_App_Block</class>
            </app>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <app>
                <class>Demo_App_Helper</class>
            </app>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <app>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <frontName>apps</frontName>
                    <module>Demo_App</module>
                </args>
            </app>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```